# IE11 not wrapping when using percentage for flex-basis

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I'm trying to get two columns displaying at 50% width, that will automatically wrap if the width becomes smaller than the available width. This code works in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't in IE11.

If I remove the `flex-basis:50%`, IE will properly wrap, but the widths are not 50% either on wide monitors.

Side Note: If I add a padding to the div elements, all the browsers wrap the content. What is the proper way of handling padding in flexbox?

```css
.flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex > div{
 flex-grow:1;
 flex-basis:50%;
}

div:first-child{
  background-color: #cfc;
}
div:last-child{
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
    </div>
</section>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/wicketr/pen/JJWvLB